# Upload Entire Directory via PHP to a remote host via FTP

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-applications

I'm using Codeigniter to create a web site, and I tried to create a function to upload the entire directory via FTP to a remote host, but nothing is working

I tried 2 functions I found, but also not working, only few files uploaded, and some files size is 0 bytes

Functions Used :

```
// 1St Function

public function ftp_copy($src_dir, $dst_dir) {
        $d = dir($src_dir);

        while($file = $d->read()) {

            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

                if (is_dir($src_dir."/".$file)) {

                    if (!@ftp_chdir($this->conn_id, $dst_dir."/".$file)) {

                        ftp_mkdir($this->conn_id, $dst_dir."/".$file);
                    }

                    ftp_copy($src_dir."/".$file, $dst_dir."/".$file);
                }
                else {

                    $upload = ftp_put($this->conn_id, $dst_dir."/".$file, $src_dir."/".$file, FTP_BINARY);
                }
            }
        }

        $d->close();
    }


// 2nd Solution from Stackoverflow question
    foreach (glob("/directory/to/upload/*.*") as $filename)
        ftp_put($ftp_stream, basename($filename) , $filename, FTP_BINARY);
```

Any solution ??

Comment: what's the function you're using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using codeigniter you can use $this->ftp->mirror() from their FTP Library.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/ftp.html

```
$this->load->library('ftp');

$config['hostname'] = 'ftp.example.com';
$config['username'] = 'your-username';
$config['password'] = 'your-password';
$config['debug']    = TRUE;

$this->ftp->connect($config);

$this->ftp->mirror('/path/to/myfolder/', '/public_html/myfolder/');

$this->ftp->close();
```

Comment: I was using mirror function, but I was passing the source directory without the trailing slash, now I added the the trailing slash and it's working.

Thank you